# Rspec para methodo delete plan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, test, rspec

Aqui va mi plan.rb completo con todos los metodos (esta dentro de /spec/features/integration):

```js
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'plan', type: 'feature' do
  # Test suite for GET /plan
  describe 'Visit /admin/plans' do
    # make HTTP get request before each example
    before(:all) do
      @plan = []
      3.times { @plan << create(:plan) }
    end

    before do
      admin = create(:user_admin)
      signin(admin.cui, admin.password)
      visit '/admin/plans'
    end

    it 'return plans', js: true do
      # Note `json` is a custom helper to parse JSON pages
      expect(page.body).not_to be_empty
      @plan.each do |plan|
        expect(page).to have_content(plan.description.to_s)
      end
    end

    it 'returns status code 200' do
      expect(page).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end
  end

  # Test suite for GET /plan/:id
  describe 'Visit /admin/plan/:id' do
    before do
      admin = create(:user_admin)
      signin(admin.cui, admin.password)
    end

    context 'When the plan exists' do
      it 'Returns the plan' do
        plan = create(:plan)
        visit("/admin/plans/#{plan.id}")
        expect(page).to have_content(plan.description)
      end

      it 'returns status code 200' do
        expect(page).to have_http_status(:ok)
      end
    end

    context 'when the record does not exist' do
      it 'returns status code 404' do
        visit('/admin/plans/100')
        expect(page).to have_http_status(:not_found)
      end
    end
  end

  # Test suite for New plan
  describe 'New /plan' do
    context 'New plan' do
      before do
        admin = create(:user_admin)
        signin(admin.cui, admin.password)
      end

      it 'create a plan' do
        visit '/admin/plans/new'
        fill_in('plan_description', with: 'Code1')
        # select('plan_gender', :from=>'Masculino')
        fill_in('plan_minimum_age', with: 1)
        fill_in('plan_maximum_age', with: 100)
        click_button('Crear')
        expect(page).to have_content('correctamente')
        expect(page).to have_http_status(:ok)
      end
    end
  end

  # Test suite for edit admin/plans
  describe 'edit /admin/plans' do
    context 'edit admin/plans' do
      before do
        admin = create(:user_admin)
        signin(admin.cui, admin.password)
      end

      it 'edit a admin/plans' do  
        plan = create(:plan)
        visit("/admin/plans/#{plan.id}/edit")
        fill_in('plan_description', with: 'Code2')
        click_button('Actualizar')
        expect(page).to have_http_status(:ok)
        expect(page).to have_content('Code2')
      end  
    end
  end

end
```

Estoy intentando realizar el test para el metodo delete de un controlador llamado 'Plan'. Lo que he intentado es lo siguiente:

```
it "deletes plan" do
 plan = FactoryBot.create(:plan)

 expect do
  delete :destroy, params: { id: plan.id }
 end.to change(Plan, :count).by(-1)
end
```

Y el error que obtengo es lo siguiente:

```
Failure/Error: delete :destroy, params: { id: plan.id } NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Plan:0x00007fc26eaa46e0>
```

Comment: Dices "el metodo delete de un modelo llamado 'Plan'.", o sea ¿esto es un test de modelo? porque `delete :destroy, params: { id: plan.id }` suena como que fuese un test de controlador. ¿que tipo es el que efectivamente quieres hacer?

Comment: Perdon, me equivoque. Es para el Controlador 'Plan'

Comment: ¿como tienes definido el encabezado del test? ¿estás usando `, type: :controller`? ¿funcionan otros métodos como `get` o `post`? ¿funciona `delete` fuera del bloque de `expect`?

Comment: Alli agregue el codigo del test completo para 'Plan'. Los demas metodos funcionan bien, cuando agregro el metodo para eliminar me arroja todo el error que mencione antes.

Answer (score 1):

Estás mezclando conceptos. Tu archivo `plan.rb` es un [feature tests](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec) (ubicados en `spec/features`), que simula la interacción de un usuario a través de la página la rendereada, por eso debes llamar a `signin` con anterioridad para poder loguearte. Por otro lado, `delete :destroy` es una llamada parte de un [controller test](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs) (ubicados en `spec/controllers`) que no necesita la interfaz web rendereada, ya que te permite acceder directamente a los actions de tu controlador a través de los verbos get/post/put/delete.

¿Cual debes usar? supongo depende de ti lo que quieras conseguir. En general un test de controlador es más rápido, ya que no necesita cargar la página en si. Por otra parte el test de integración o feature suele ser más completo ya que a la vez estás testeando lo que el usuario final verá en la pantalla. Aparte para este último deberías testear de que el elemento borrado ya no se muestre en pantalla en vez de contar directamente la cantidad de planes en tu BD, ya que para el test de integración tu sistema es una caja negra y si, puedes llamar a `Plan.count`, pero en general es una mala práctica porque el usuario no tendría por qué tener acceso directamente a la información manejada en el backend y si hay algún elemento en la interfaz que te permita dilucidar ese dato, es mejor que testees eso.

Comment: Lo raro es que aun asi haciendo el signin y utilizando el codigo anterior sigo obteniendo el siguiente error: undefined method `delete' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Plan::DeleteAdminPlans::DeleteAdminPlans:0x00007fad6b568428> ------ De que manera deberia realizar mi test para el metodo 'destroy' como un feature test?? Muchas gracias.

Comment: @francofernandez insisto, no te va a resultar llamar a `delete` porque es un método que **solo existe para controller test**, en un feature test **no existe esa llamada**. ¿como llamar a destroy de un feature test? eso solo tu lo sabes, tu sabes si está implementado en alguna parte un botón para borrar planes en la interfaz, luego ahí ejecutas un `click_button` sobre ese elemento igual que en los otros tests que has hecho. Te insisto, un feature tests es para emular el actuar de un usuario en la interfaz, no tendría por qué saber de la existencia de un `delete :destroy` en un controlador.